# central page info css and html

Tags: html, css

my page must be like this: https://ibb.co/Z1tZGs3
for now i have created that header strip and footer strip but how can I make central page info like praesent and lorem ipsum someone can help me pls? maybe I have to add a navbar between header and footer but i don't know how to do that and how can i cut footer strip like right side i want to cut some width.

```css
body{
    background-color: #ffff;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: harmy;
}

header{
     background-color: #9cd5e8;
     margin-bottom: -10px;
     color:#838478


}
header.cut{
    margin-right:50px;
}

h1.light{
font-weight: lighter;
}


.cut{

    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;

}

 .footer{
   background-color: #7fbec0;
 position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />

  <title>ORIZZONTE VIAGGI</title>
  <style>
  @font-face {

  font-family: harmy;

  src: url('./font.woff');

}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="cut">
   <header>
           <h1 class="light">&nbsp;Orizzonte Viaggi</h1>

   </header>
   <img src="img/beach.jpg" alt="" width="1515" height="420"/>

   </div>
        <div class="cut">
   <div class="footer">

             <p>
                  © 2020 <u>Harman</u>
   </p>
           </div>
   </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why do you fixe your footer ? My proposal comes

Comment: on right side i must cut it and fit with header and img it must be similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my proposal based on your model

```css
body{
    background-color: #ffff;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: harmy;
}


#bodyCenter{
  margin-left:25px;
  margin-right:25px;
}

header{
     background-color: #9cd5e8;
     margin-bottom: -10px;
     color:#838478;
     margin-right:40px;
}

h1.light{
font-weight: lighter;
}

#bigPicture{
  width:100%; /*will take 100% from bodyCenter available width*/
}

 footer{
   background-color: #7fbec0;
 /*position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;*/
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />

  <title>ORIZZONTE VIAGGI</title>
  <style>
  @font-face {

  font-family: harmy;

  src: url('./font.woff');

}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="bodyCenter">
   <header>
     <h1 class="light">&nbsp;Orizzonte Viaggi</h1>
   </header>

<img src="https://s2.qwant.com/thumbr/474x325/d/e/3357a239e6aeeb0497d846500eaf15f26a80324945abb2de8bdaef07e06823/th.jpg?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.UKfu8ufBwKPECTmhud4_cQHaFF%26pid%3DApi&q=0&b=1&p=0&a=0" id="bigPicture">

   <div>
   
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus convallis nibh id leo aliquet porta. Etiam euismod pretium mi vitae pretium. Cras eu nibh molestie, venenatis mauris vitae, auctor elit. Fusce fermentum sed ante vel fringilla. Maecenas auctor nec quam nec rutrum. Quisque eu pharetra tortor. Integer nec purus convallis, interdum urna et, tempor tortor. Morbi tristique hendrerit libero quis fermentum. Praesent fringilla fermentum nisl. Integer faucibus sit amet lacus vitae tincidunt. Pellentesque convallis augue eget ligula consectetur tincidunt. Sed cursus volutpat lorem, non rhoncus urna placerat et.

In rutrum gravida sodales. Integer commodo mi quam, et luctus arcu porta sit amet. Suspendisse potenti. Nullam sed lobortis ex. Phasellus commodo ornare velit, quis viverra nulla rhoncus ac. Nulla facilisi. Praesent congue felis eu orci fringilla consequat. In vitae finibus lorem. Aliquam convallis molestie lectus, quis sagittis mauris accumsan et. Sed luctus, turpis vel mattis vehicula, tellus ligula ornare urna, non mattis dolor elit eu lacus.
   
   </div>
   <footer>

      <p>© 2020 <u>Harman</u></p>
   </footer>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how can i add a side bar  and image in that lorem ipsum..? like in the picture https://ibb.co/Z1tZGs3

Comment: Just like with an ordinary web page. I will modify my code to show you how to add an image.

Comment: Be careful with the desire to set up fixed widths. If you set a fixed width to your side bar, then you let the web page calculate the width of your text block automatically.

Comment: how can i block footer under because it's going up when i put image

Comment: With my proposal, the footer is at the end of the page. So if you want to add something as content, add it before <footer> tag